# Difference between 'in' and 'on' - "Pamphlets were dropped on the city" or "in the city"

Tags: prepositions, difference

In the following sentence, could 'in' be possibly used instead of 'on'? Is there a difference?

> Pamphlets were dropped **on** the city to warn the civilians to flee from the attack of their enemies.

Comment: Dropped? I am thinking of disseminating them rather than dropping them. Were the pamphlets thrown/dropped from an aeroplane? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, it's from an aeroplane. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 12):

> Leaflets were dropped **on** the city to warn the civilians to flee from the attack of their enemies.

The preposition **on** is used to make clear that the leaflets were dropped from above: [from an aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_leaflet_propaganda) of some kind, most likely. Those who dropped the leaflets were not inside the city.

(I substituted "pamphlets" with "leaflets", since this seems more plausible)

> Leaflets were dropped **in** the city to warn the civilians to flee from the attack of their enemies.

This would mean that someone who was **inside** the city dropped the leaflets. This would be a more dangerous task in a war situation, since one could be captured by the enemy in the city.

---

You can also use **over** instead of **on**:

"A US helicopter **drops leaflets over** a village near Hawijah in Kirkuk province, Iraq, on March 6, 2008" ([Wikipedia Commons image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:UH-60_PSYOP_Leaflet_Drop,_near_Hawijah,_Iraq_06_March_2008.jpg))

[image]

---

And this is a picture showing leaflets being distributed **in** a city. "Wu Songtao, a college student from Zhejiang province tries to earn some extra money by distributing leaflets **in** Hefei, East China's Anhui province."

[image]

---

Teachers drop leaflets **in** the congress building in the Valparaíso Region, Chile ([2011](http://xrenb.livejournal.com/204862.html)). The teachers are **inside** the building.

[image]

Comment: That substitution provides clarity. (+1) pamphlets dropped may not be spread by air friction/resistance . I am over-thinking of course.

Comment: With each photo, you are improving the answer! :)

Comment: @MaulikV - thank you, Maulik! A picture is worth a thousand words (and tens of thousands of prepositions)! (0:

Answer (score 2):

Something *dropped* on the city. It's clear that when you drop something 'on' something, it's from certain height *(He **dropped** the chandelier **on** the ground)*.

Yes, it's dropping the literature/paper mostly from an airplane/helicopter. Check out the similar example

> [US **drops** atomic bomb **on Hiroshima**](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/august/6/newsid_3602000/3602189.stm)